# WhatsApp Click to Chat without phone number is not working

Tags: iphone, whatsapp

In it's FAQ, WhatsApp explains how to create a new, prefilled message where the user can choose the contact to send the message to:
"To create a link with just a pre-filled message" from the FAQ Page here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app
The link looks like this: https://wa.me/?text=I%27m%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing (example from the FAQ Page).

However, since a few days this seems not to work anymore on iOS and Desktop (Android Phones seems not to be affected yet). 
The link with a phone number (https://wa.me/123456789?text=The%20message%20to%20send) is working just fine. The workaround with just adding "0" as the phone number doesn't work either as whatsApp will throw an error that the contact could not be found.

Has anyone else run into the same problem? And found a soution / workaround?

Comment: checked the link you've provided just now on my iphone and it works as expected. It was a bug that they fixed, probably

Answer (score 0):

Your URL seems to be wrong. You need to append URL path which is `/send` in your URL string. You seem to be adding the URLQueries right after the base URL. Also, use `addingPercentEncoding` for encoding.

```
guard
    let urlString = "whatsapp://send?text=\(text)"
        .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let unwrappedUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return nil
}
```

Comment: It's not the encoding of the URL.
1. The URL is copied directly from the WhatsApp FAQ
2. As soon as you add a phone number (between the / and the ?) it works:
 [https://wa.me/0?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing](https://wa.me/0?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing)

Comment: Did you try out with the URL that I just provided?

Comment: whatsapp:// links do not work on any devices / browsers.